# Why isn't .bashrc read when switching user?

Tags: bash, rhel, su

On RHEL7 I see a different behaviour with startup scripts when I `su` to a user with `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` as the shell, despite the fact that `/bin/sh` points to `/bin/bash`

I've got the following scripts set up for the user:

**/home/my_user/.profile**

```
echo Hello from .profile
```

**/home/my_user/.bash_profile**

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH

echo Hello from .bash_profile
```

**/home/my_user/.bashrc**

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
echo Hello from .bashrc
```

Now when I `su` and specify `/bin/bash` I get the following output.

```
[batwad@hellodave ~]$ sudo su -s /bin/bash my_user
Hello from .bashrc
[my_user@hellodave batwad]$
```

Does this mean `.bash_profile` wasn't executed?  After all, I don't see "Hello from .bash_profile"

Now when I `su` and specify `/bin/sh` (which links to `/bin/bash` anyway) I get the following output.

```
[batwad@hellodave ~]$ sudo su -s /bin/sh my_user
sh-4.2$
```

No echoes and a different shell prompt.  What gives?

### Update

Following redseven's answer I tried adding `-l` and got yet another behaviour!

```
[bawtad@hellodave ~]$ sudo su -l -s /bin/sh my_user
Last login: Thu Aug 16 11:44:38 UTC 2018 on pts/0
Hello from .profile
-sh-4.2$
```

It's `.profile` that is used this time!  Note the "Last login" part didn't appear on the first try.

Comment: Just a note, that it is not a good idea to output something is .bashrc script, as it may cause problems with scp and other tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in behaviour you see is a standard feature of `bash` to insure a full compatibility for plain standard Bourne shell environments.

From the mouth of the standard `bash` man page (type `/INVOCATION`):

> If  bash  is  invoked  with  the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup
>          behavior of historical versions of sh as  closely  as  possible,  while
>          conforming  to the POSIX standard as well.

Comment: Lesson learned: if you want bash, specify `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue in `Ubuntu 20.04.3` and that was because of these lines inside `~/.bashrc`:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

The solution for me was to move the important commands inside `~/.bashrc` before that block (basically the lines needed to load nvm and node.js).

Comment: Or something like this `[[ $- != *i* ]] && return` at first line

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use all your settings when you normally have after a login the best way to use the `-l` (or simple `-`) option for su:

man su:

```
       -, -l, --login
       Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in
       directly.
```

With the `-l` option your ~./bash_profile will be used (and your .bashrc as well if it's included into your .bash_profile), otherwise your shell is not a login shell and only the ~/.bashrc will be used.

These are only true if your shell is bash. If you have a different default shell or you specify a different shell with -s option then it all depends how that shell works (which may use or may ignore bash settings). Even if /bin/sh is a symlink to the bash binary it's a different shell, the binary detect which way you started it and starts a different shell not bash.

Comment: Cool, that yields a different behaviour again!  What if I were to expand a little and give the reason for `/sbin/nologin' as the user's shell is that it's a service account used to launch an application with an init script, and the `su` command is part of that script?  Would I want that to be a login shell?

Answer (score 0):

If the bash starts as interactive non-login shell it search for the `~/.bash_bashrc`, `~/.bashrc` for user-specific configuration and `/etc/bash.bashrc` for system wide configuration (refer to bash man page).

But if it is run as an interactive login shell(which can be done by appending `--login`) it first looks for `~/.profile`or `~/.bash_profile`(whatever is availabe.. in your case it hits the `~/.profile` so it won't bother reading the `~/.bash_profile`) for user-specific configuration and `/etc/profile` for system-wide configs

If you want to source both files add this to your .bashrc file

```
 if [ -f $HOME/.profile ]; then
     . /etc/profile
 fi
```